# Output list of files from slideshow

Tags: python, for-loop, pyglet

I have adapted a python script to display a slideshow of images.  The original script can be found at https://github.com/cgoldberg/py-slideshow

I want to be able to record the filename of each of the images that is displayed so that I may more easily debug any errors (i.e., remove incompatible images).

I have attempted to include a command to write the filename to a text file in the `def get_image_paths` function.  However, that has not worked.  My code appears below - any help is appreciated.

```
import pyglet
import os
import random
import argparse

window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=True)

def get_scale(window, image):
    if image.width > image.height:
        scale = float(window.width) / image.width
    else:
        scale = float(window.height) / image.height
    return scale


def update_image(dt):
    img = pyglet.image.load(random.choice(image_paths))
    sprite.image = img
    sprite.scale = get_scale(window, img)
    if img.height >= img.width:
        sprite.x = ((window.width / 2) - (sprite.width / 2))
        sprite.y = 0
    elif img.width >= img.height:
        sprite.y = ((window.height / 2) - (sprite.height / 2))
        sprite.x = 0
    else:
        sprite.x = 0
        sprite.y = 0
     window.clear()

thefile=open('test.txt','w')
def get_image_paths(input_dir='.'):
    paths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir, topdown=True):
        for file in sorted(files):
            if file.endswith(('jpg', 'png', 'gif')):
                path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
                paths.append(path)
            thefile.write(file)
    return paths


@window.event()
def on_draw():
   sprite.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('dir', help='directory of images',
                        nargs='?', default=os.getcwd())
    args = parser.parse_args()
    image_paths = get_image_paths(args.dir)
    img = pyglet.image.load(random.choice(image_paths))
    sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img)
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update_image, 3)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: better use `logging` module to write in log file.

Comment: maybe you have to close file.

Comment: `sprite` is never declared in `update_image` - Is this a programming error or a result of you stripping down the code?

Comment: Definitely a result of my stripping the code down. What are best practices? I've been looking at documentation.

Answer (score 1):

System don't have to write to file at once but it can keep text in buffer and saves when you close file. So probably you have to close file.

Or you can use `thefile.flush()` after every `thefile.write()` to send new text from buffer to file at once.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up declaring the random image chosen to a variable that I, then, wrote to a txt file.  Relevant code with changes appears below:

```
thefile=open('test.txt','w')

def update_image(dt):
pic = random.choice(image_paths)
img = pyglet.image.load(pic)
thefile.write(pic+'\n')
thefile.flush()
sprite.image = img
sprite.scale = get_scale(window, img)
if img.height >= img.width:
    sprite.x = ((window.width / 2) - (sprite.width / 2))
    sprite.y = 0
elif img.width >= img.height:
    sprite.y = ((window.height / 2) - (sprite.height / 2))
    sprite.x = 0
else:
    sprite.x = 0
    sprite.y = 0
window.clear()
```

Thank you @furas for pointing me in the right direction regarding log files and flushing the buffer to be certain to capture all instances.